# how to remove backslash from the json data in c#

Tags: c#, json

I want to get datatable data in the json data, but while I am converting I am getting data with backslash symbol. how to remove the backslash or how to generate json data without backslash.

output data

```
 "[{\"Date\":\"2020-03-27T00:00:00\",\"Units\":1035.0},{\"Date\":\"2020-03-26T00:00:00\",\"Units\":1137.0},{\"Date\":\"2020-03-25T00:00:00\",\"Units\":1283.0},{\"Date\":\"2020-03-24T00:00:00\",\"Units\":635.0}]"
```

code

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public string GetFanHoursReport(string fromdate, string todate)
{
    string jsondata = "";
    using (ColdStorageAppEntities entities = new ColdStorageAppEntities())
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon_coldstorage))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd_getlatest = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * from RawData", con);
                SqlDataAdapter da_getlatest = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd_getlatest);
                DataTable dt_getlatest = new DataTable();
                da_getlatest.Fill(dt_getlatest);
                jsondata=DataTableToJSONWithJSONNet(dt_getlatest);
            }

            return jsondata;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

convertion code -

```
public string DataTableToJSONWithJSONNet(DataTable table)
{
    string JSONString = string.Empty;
    JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table);
    return JSONString;
}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkTds.png)

Comment: Are you seeing the backslash while debugging?

Comment: It is a string containing double-quotes `"`. The double quotes are _escaped_ with a backslash (meaning written `\"` ) inside the string, because the string delimiter at sstart and end are already double quotes. It seems ok for me, the string actually as no backslash in it. When are you seeing this ?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the backslashes only appear when you're viewing the string in a debugger. If you were to write

```
Console.WriteLine(jsondata);
```

you can confirm whether the string contains the extra escape characters.